Omada Controller and rsyslog
I am totally new to rsyslog so please be gentle ;)
I have an Omada TP-Link controler, that manages all my clients AP across the region.
Everything works fine, I am trying to implement public Wi-Fi access. In order to do so, I need some real log collecting method. I chose to implement rsyslog, and ElasticStack (Logstash, Elasticsearch & Kibana).
The message rsyslog receive from Omada is the following :
2024-04-03T07:50:11+02:00 {{AP_IP}} [{{Random_ID}}] AP MAC={{AP_MAC}} MAC SRC={{Client_MAC}} IP SRC={{Client_IP}} IP DST={{IP_Dst}} IP proto={{IP_Protocol}} SPT={{Client_Port}} DPT={{Dst_Port}}#015#012[{{Random_ID}}] AP MAC={{AP_MAC}} MAC SRC={{Client_MAC}} IP SRC={{Client_IP}} IP DST={{IP_Dst}} IP proto={{IP_Protocol}} SPT={{Client_Port}} DPT={{Dst_Port}}#015#012[{{Random_ID}}] AP MAC={{AP_MAC}} MAC SRC={{Client_MAC}} IP SRC={{Client_IP}} IP DST={{IP_Dst}} IP proto={{IP_Protocol}} SPT={{Client_Port}} DPT={{Dst_Port}}#015

So basically, we have in one message multiple logs. Every message starts with the timestamp, then the IP of the AP, then all the logs with an ID foreach. The problem I have is that every log is separated by the string "#015#012".
In order to manage logs with Kibana, I need to send the log in json format to Logstash. I do so with the following template :
module(load="omelasticsearch")

template(name="template_prod"
        type="string"
        string="%$.mymsg%"
        option.json="on") {
                constant(value="{")
                constant(value="\"@timestamp\":\"") property(name="timereported" dateFormat="rfc3339")
                constant(value="\",\"ap_ip\":\"") property(name="hostname")
                constant(value="\",\"omada_id\":\"") property(name="procid")
                constant(value="\",\"ap_mac\":\"") property(name="msg" regex.expression="AP MAC=([0-9a-fA-F:]+)" regex.type="ERE" regex.submatch="1")
                constant(value="\",\"client_mac\":\"") property(name="msg" regex.expression="MAC SRC=([0-9a-fA-F:]+)" regex.type="ERE" regex.submatch="1")
                constant(value="\",\"client_ip\":\"") property(name="msg" regex.expression="IP SRC=([0-9.]+)" regex.type="ERE" regex.submatch="1")
                constant(value="\",\"dest_ip\":\"") property(name="msg" regex.expression="IP DST=([0-9.]+)" regex.type="ERE" regex.submatch="1")
                constant(value="\",\"ip_prot\":\"") property(name="msg" regex.expression="IP proto=([0-9]+)" regex.type="ERE" regex.submatch="1")
                constant(value="\",\"src_port\":\"") property(name="msg" regex.expression="SPT=([0-9]+)" regex.type="ERE" regex.submatch="1")
                constant(value="\",\"dst_port\":\"") property(name="msg" regex.expression="DPT=([0-9]+)" regex.type="ERE" regex.submatch="1")
                constant(value="\"}")
         }

if $msg contains '{{AP1_MAC_Client1}}' OR $msg contains '{{AP2_MAC_Client1}}' OR $msg contains '{{AP3_MAC_Client1}}' then {
        set $.mymsg = replace($msg, "#015", "\n");
        set $.mymsg = replace($.mymsg, "#012", "");
        action(type="omelasticsearch"
                server="{{elastic_ip}}"
                serverport="{{elastic_port}}"
                template="template_prod"
                searchIndex="client1"
                searchType="ap_log"
                maxbytes="100m"
                queue.type="linkedlist"
                queue.size="5000"
                queue.dequeuebatchsize="300"
                action.resumeretrycount="-1")
} else {
        action(type="omfile" file="/var/log/clients/other.log")
}

And I seem to confuse myself right here, because I use option.json in a string template, so I get :
rsyslogd: template 'template_prod' is not a list template but has parameters specified - ignored [v8.2302.0]

So my final question is, with my current configuration, is there a way to send logs to Logstash in a json format given the bad format of the log at the beginning ?
Thanks a lot for your help !

Is #015#012 the string rsyslog receives via UDP, or is it the string rsyslog writes to your logfiles? That looks suspiciously like a \r\n that rsyslog has translated.
